# After installing Hadoop via Cloudera Manager 4.5 HDFS only points to the local filesystem

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cloudera

After install Cloudera Manager 4.5 I find that it's not configured to point to the correct default filesystem. If I run `haddop fs -ls /` from one of the tasktracker/datanode boxes I just get the local filesystem.

But when I check core-site.xml from in cloudera, I see this setting, which seems like it might be correct:

```
<property>
  <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
  <value>hdfs://hadoop-namenode1:8020</value>
</property>
```

Any idea what I should be looking for here exactly?

```
davidparks21@hadoop-reducedslot2:~$ hadoop fs -ls /
Found 22 items
drwxr-xr-x   - root root       4096 2013-04-12 13:05 /bin
drwxr-xr-x   - root root       4096 2012-04-19 09:32 /boot
drwxr-xr-x   - root root       4096 2013-04-12 11:53 /dev
drwxr-xr-x   - root root       4096 2013-04-15 04:26 /dfs
drwxr-xr-x   - root root       4096 2013-04-15 05:52 /etc
drwxr-xr-x   - root root       4096 2013-03-30 02:44 /home
drwxr-xr-x   - root root       4096 2013-03-29 11:30 /lib
drwxr-xr-x   - root root       4096 2013-03-29 11:30 /lib64
drwxr-xr-x   - root root       4096 2013-04-15 04:44 /mapred
drwxr-xr-x   - root root       4096 2013-03-29 11:19 /media
drwxr-xr-x   - root root       4096 2012-04-19 09:32 /mnt
drwxr-xr-x   - root root       4096 2013-04-12 13:09 /opt
dr-xr-xr-x   - root root          0 2013-04-12 11:53 /proc
drwx------   - root root       4096 2013-04-10 09:49 /root
drwxr-xr-x   - root root        480 2013-04-15 05:52 /run
drwxr-xr-x   - root root       4096 2013-03-29 11:31 /sbin
drwxr-xr-x   - root root       4096 2012-03-05 17:54 /selinux
drwxr-xr-x   - root root       4096 2013-03-29 11:19 /srv
dr-xr-xr-x   - root root          0 2013-04-12 11:53 /sys
drwxrwxrwt   - root root       4096 2013-04-15 05:52 /tmp
drwxr-xr-x   - root root       4096 2013-03-29 11:19 /usr
drwxr-xr-x   - root root       4096 2013-03-29 11:19 /var
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, it wasn't clear to me that you need to "deploy client configuration" from cloudera manager.

Running this command helped me figure that out:

```
davidparks21@hadoop-reducedslot2:~$ hdfs getconf -confKey fs.defaultFS
file:///
```

[image]